# How to enable USB debug on Note 2?

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-note-2

No matter what setting I change, my Samsung Note 2 is always entering "USB media mode" instead of "debug mode".

I have the USB debug option set and the Google USB driver from the SDK installed, but `adb devices` shows nothing.

Enabling USB debug on my Nexus and plugging it in gives the debug mode just fine and `adb devices` shows it.
If I plug the USB in the Note 2 with USB debug enabled, the notification shows *"Connected as media device"*.

<sup>If relevant my device is running Android v4.1.2.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I had to download Samsung's USB drivers for this device from their [support page](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I317).

After you have the driver installed, when you plug in the device, Windows search windows.com for updates and finds:

```
Samsung mobile usb composite device
Samsung-sgh-i317
Samsung mobile usb modem
Samsung Android ADB Interface
```

Now, the interface still shows the *"Connected as a media device"* message, but `adb devices` list can see it.

Comment: Yepp. That's the usual thing with Windows and Android devices: You have to install the driver first :)

Comment: Was assuming all devices correctly implemented the google USB drive... and when i realized not, had some trouble finding the actual drive. Samsung support is a mess.